# Share i18next translations between nextjs and component workspaces

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next, react-i18next, yarn-workspaces

We have a yarn 2 monorepo setup with the following workspaces:

```
/root
  /app (nextjs)
  /components (individual react functional components)
  /storybook
  /constants
```

Currently, /app has the i18next translation files stored local to the workspace, but I would like to move that into the constants workspace so that all workspaces can share the same translations.  I had no issue moving the translations there and loading them in both the /app and /storybook workspaces.

Also, currently, all translations happen only in /app.  The /components workspace has no translations, and the translated text is passed in props to the dumb components.  So, a component in /app looks something like this:

```
import ListBox from "@root/components/ListBox";
import {useTranslation} from "react-i18next";

export default const Page() {
  const [t] = useTranslation();
  const label = t("listBoxLabel"); // <-- exists in en.json as a key
  
  return (
    <div>
      <ListBox label={label} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

As such, storybook also has to provide the "label" prop to render the component in stories, doing this in pretty much the same manner.

What I would like to do is instead translate the text at the /components workspace level, so that the translations can be done in one place, where it's used, to reduce prop drilling and also simplify things.

Something like this:
/components/ListBox.js:

```
import {useTranslation} from "react-i18next";

export default const ListBox() {
  const [t] = useTranslation();
  const label = t("listBoxLabel"); // <-- exists in en.json as a key
  
  return <p>{label}</p>
}
```

When I run this code, it just prints out the translation key "listBoxLabel", in both storybook and the nextjs app.

I was able to fix storybook by wrapping stories with I18nextProvider and changing the dependencies in the /components workspace for i18next and react-i18next to move them from a normal dependency to a peer dependency, and storybook properly renders the translation.  However, then the NextJS /app throws an error that the react-i18next Module Not Found when it imports the /components/ListBox.js code.  It seems to require the /components workspace keep a normal dependency for that, but doesn't translate it in that case.  If I remove the /components dependencies altogether, /storybook won't compile and start for the same reason.

Duplicating this exact code in the app or storybook, however, displays the correct translation.  So, it has something to do with importing it from a sibling workspace in the monorepo, and I'm not sure exactly how to go about fixing that for the nextjs app.

Just a note: I don't use the next-i18next component.  Instead, I am simply using react-i18next directly, without any providers configured.  I did attempt to wrap the app with the I18nextProvider component similar to the storybook stories, but it didn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas where to look further or what to try for this? I would think loading a component from a workspace component library where the translations happen within the library would be a common scenario, but I haven't been able to find anyone else running into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what's causing this, but it appears to be a nextjs, webpack, or yarn bug.  I discovered the problem was related to this in my tsconfig.js file in the @root/app workspace:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@root/components/*": ["../components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to fix this by removing this setting, but it broke other code (some components were typescript), so I just explicitly declared those component modules in the custom.d.ts file as modules.

Where the next/yarn bug comes in: after I removed this line, and restarted the dev server, the i18n translations were still broken.  Until I went and touched the components/ListBox.js file.  This caused something to rebuild within next, and the translations showed up.

The ListBox.js file is not typescript, so I don't understand why this causes a problem.

While trying to resolve this issue, yarn kept getting into a bad state, next was telling me I didn't have typescript installed when I did, and multiple other tedious random errors...what a mess.